# TokBox rotate video image in a web app

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox, video-conferencing

I am developing a videoconference app using the OpenTok platform and I am experiencing a issue rotating the video screen.

Assuming that at the other end I have a phone user video-calling, he might turn his phone changing from portrait/landscape to landscape/portrait. At the same time this phone app will be sending the orientation via data channel and in the site I will rotate the video accordingly using something like:

```
switch (event.data) {
          case 'portrait up':
            video_container.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
            break;
          case 'portrait down':
            video_container.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';
            break;
          case 'landscape left':
            video_container.style.transform = 'rotate(270deg)';
            break;
          case 'landscape right':
            video_container.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
            break;
}
```

The problem with this is that the image never uses all the available container. For example, in portrait I am seeing:

[image]
Is there any easy way to fix this without cutting off part of the image?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to rotate the video yourself, OpenTok should handle that. Are you using the opentok.js library? What browser are you using on the mobile side? Chrome or Firefox for Android? Safari Beta on iOS 11?

Comment: Hi @AdamUllman I am using "opentok": "2"/2.8 SDK in the webapp and 2.8 SDK in the iOS app, it is an iOS swift app connecting to a web app

Comment: Those are really old versions. Have you tried using the latest version, v2.11?